# Can we apply themes in an C#.net Application?

Tags: c#

Can we apply themes in an C#.net Application?

Comment: ASP.Net? WPF? WinForms? XUL? Silverlight?

Comment: Please be more specific when you put questions. The question is too ambiguos, it could be about WPF, Windows Forms, ASP.NET, MVC...

Comment: This depends on your GUI toolkit. WinForms, WPF, GTK#,... Themes work differently for different toolkits.

Comment: You guys, give the OP a chance to update the question before you close. He's new here.

Comment: exact duplicate of my question which I asked 17 days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087218/how-can-i-apply-my-own-theme-to-my-windows-form-application/4087338#4087338

Comment: themes in C#.net in windows application in visual studio 2008!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

If you want details, please supply details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party DLL which can do your task [DotNetSkin](http://www.dotnetskin.net/)