# change scrollbar color for a control in c#

Tags: c#, colors, controls, scrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing color of scroll bar in ListView in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397025/changing-color-of-scroll-bar-in-listview-in-winforms)

I am trying to change default colors of a scroll bars for a listview in my desktop application. I guess it can be done through inheariting from default class. Would you mind giving some code or tips?

Comment: duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397025/changing-color-of-scroll-bar-in-listview-in-winforms

Comment: It can't.  Scrollbars are one of the *hard* window adornments to custom-draw, the native Windows controls do not support it at all.  You'll always get them in the colors selected by the user's preferred theme.  Which, well, the user prefers.

Comment: Check my answer that proposes an alternative workaround to replace the default controls ScrollBar with custom ones https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613569/5514131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [Changing color of scroll bar in ListView in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397025/changing-color-of-scroll-bar-in-listview-in-winforms)

Another way is to make your listview in a **WPF** control, wpf allows scrollbar customization, look here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SBar06292009105859AM/SBar.aspx