# Customizable scrollbar in Treeview control in winforms

Tags: treeview, scrollbar

I need to modify the colors of a scrollbar for a treeview control in my winforms application.

I tried to use the similar logic in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336874/how-to-change-the-back-color-of-the-scrollbar-of-a-panel[text](Customscrollbar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73336874/how-to-change-the-back-color-of-the-scrollbar-of-a-panel%5Btext%5D(Customscrollbar))
But as treeview control not derived from Scrollable control, I am unable to use that approach.

If anybody has any idea around this, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.