# Changing the color of scrollbar in dataGridview in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the windows form in which I have used DataGridView and now I want to change the color of these scrollbars. I got one solution also on CodeProject but its not working . The Code which I have Used is as below

`foreach (Control child in DataGridview1.Controls)
            {
                child.Enabled = true;
                child.IsAccessible = true;
                child.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                child.BackColor = Color.Green;
                child.Width = 5;
            }`

but it doesn't changes the color of the scrollbars.

I am not getting what else needs to be done. 
Also is there any other way to do this .

Comment: There is a post in SO which says it's not possible in Winforms but you can do it if u use Custom Scroolbars. Here is the link :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C

Comment: It's seems you have already posted the same question in SO:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380461/how-to-change-the-color-of-scrollbars-of-datagridview

Comment: but in this question I have mentioned the code which I have used and which is not working . Thats why i posted this in new thread. So is there any modification to get that code work.

Comment: It's winforms, so it's not possible. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397025/changing-color-of-scroll-bar-in-listview-in-winforms If it's wpf it's possible. The scrollbar for Datagridview or ListView, it's doesn't matter.

Comment: @linguini: Thanks ..!!!Then may be I should use something like   WebBrowsercontrol.

Comment: Refer the link i have posted in previous comments. As i told you, it's possible by using custom one but not by default one.