# Changing ListView scrollbar colors

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to customize Win32 controls such as buttons, edits and statics etc.
Couple days ago I was trying to customize a ListView, I've changed pretty much everything about It's look but then I realized It's scrollbars. I didn't like the white scrollbars over a dark theme based ListView. I've made some search and found out that I could use WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR so I immediately changed the ListView's subclass and tried the WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR but failed to get any result. Then I thought maybe sublcass function doesn't work at all and tried couple drawing on WM_NCPAINT and It was working. So only thing that was not working was the WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR. Then I made a new clean project and made a simple Window and a ListView in it then changed the subclass just to see if It works on a clean project or not, and It did not. Here is an example that doesn't work:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

bool isRunning = false;
int exitCode = 0;

HFONT listViewFont;

LRESULT CALLBACK ListViewProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR idSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR: {
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;

        SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(240, 240, 240));

        return (LRESULT)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(240, 240, 240));
    } break;
    default:
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE: {
        HWND listView = CreateWindowA("SysListView32", "", WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER, 50, 50, 250, 20 * 20, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        SetWindowSubclass(listView, ListViewProc, 0, 0);
        ListView_SetBkColor(listView, RGB(51, 51, 51));
        ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(listView, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
        SendMessageA(listView, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)listViewFont, NULL);
        ShowWindow(listView, true);
        UpdateWindow(listView);

        LVCOLUMN column;
        column.mask = LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT;
        column.pszText = LPWSTR(L"Column");
        column.cx = 250;
        ListView_InsertColumn(listView, 0, &column);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            LVITEM item;
            item.pszText = LPWSTR(L"item");
            item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
            item.iItem = i;
            item.iSubItem = 0;
            ListView_InsertItem(listView, &item);
        };
    } break;
    case WM_CLOSE: {
        isRunning = false;
        PostQuitMessage(exitCode);
    } break;
    default: {
        return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    } break;
    };
    return DefWindowProcA(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
};

void InitFonts() {
    listViewFont = CreateFontA(
        16, 
        0, 0, 0, 
        FW_NORMAL, 
        FALSE, 
        FALSE, 
        FALSE, 
        DEFAULT_CHARSET,
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        DEFAULT_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE,
        "Georgia"
    );
};

int main() {
    InitFonts();

    WNDCLASSEXA wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = "_MainWindow";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;

    RegisterClassExA(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, "_MainWindow", "", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 500, 200, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, true);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    isRunning = true;

    MSG msg;
    while (isRunning) {
        if (GetMessageA(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageA(&msg);
        };
    };

    return exitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the scroll bars in the ListView control are not the scroll bar controls. `WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR message` is used to set the background color of the `scroll bar control`.

As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't change the ListView scrollbar colors via `WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR message`. And you just could set three colors for a list-view control: Text color, Text background color and Window background color.

Refer to the Docs:

[List-View Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#list-view-colors)

[WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorscrollbar)

Comment: This can't be true. There has to be a way to modify it. And I also want to know why WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR did not work. At least being able to change It's background color is something, right?

Comment: You could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4397402

Comment: @ErkanDemirci it is true, the scrollbars of a listview control are not normal scrollbars, the control reimplements it's own scrollbars. But they look exactly the same as normal Windows scrollbars even though they have the same look.