# (C#) How to make a dark mode theme in windows forms (separate form as select theme menu)

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how I can code a dark theme radio button that turns my entire C# windows form dark (including menus etc)

I made a separate settings form and I want to have radio buttons for themes that change the theme in the whole program, not just the settings menu. I'm making a text editor.

Comment: (I couldnt find anything working like that what i described online)

Comment: This is far too broad for stack overflow. Find a tutorial online or in a book, give it a try, and come back if you get stuck on something specific!!

Comment: I didnt find anything online that does what i want and i dont have any coding books.

Comment: Less than a minute of searching *"c# how to create a theme for a winforms application"* turned up these results: [Apply your own theme to a Windows forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087218/how-can-i-apply-my-own-theme-to-my-windows-forms-application), [Implementing your own color theme](https://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/implementing-your-own-colour-themes-in-a-c-windows-forms-application/), [How to create a theme option for controls in windows form in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1098586/How-to-create-a-theme-option-for-controls-in-windo)

Comment: @HolzkopfBude: You need to code for the entire form when the radio button changes its value. You could get info on dark and light mode and many helpful videos on YouTube by searching 'winforms ui c#'

Answer (score 20):

- Step 1: Decide on how you want to store your color schemes and create a class based on it.
- Step 2: Create a method that changes the color of every UI component within the container, like this:

```cs
public void ChangeTheme(ColorScheme scheme, Control.ControlCollection container)
{
    foreach (Control component in container)
    {
        if (component is Panel)
        {
            ChangeTheme(scheme, component.Controls);
            component.BackColor = scheme.PanelBG;
            component.ForeColor = scheme.PanelFG;
        }
        else if (component is Button)
        {
            component.BackColor = scheme.ButtonBG;
            component.ForeColor = scheme.ButtonFG;
        }
        else if (component is TextBox)
        {
            component.BackColor = scheme.TextBoxBG;
            component.ForeColor = scheme.TextBoxFG;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

- Step 3: Call that method whenever you open new form on its components (and also make sure the form isn't visible before the method is done for obvious reasons) or whenever you change the theme.

Answer (score 1):

I actually made a Class "DarkModeCS" to automatically Apply DarkMode Color into all your Controls.

Check it: https://github.com/BlueMystical/Dark-Mode-Forms